# What is the equaivalent of shiny.io for Matlab for building web interface

Tags: r, matlab, shiny

Like you can create web interfaces that feed data to your R code and can show your R plots in shiny.io, I wonder if there's a similar interface for Matlab so I can get the parameters from the user and feed it into my Matlab code and eventually show the Matlab results and plots (interactively) to the user. Thanks for any suggestions ahead of time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Matlab is very bad with dynamic dashboards where you can feed data in and run arbitrary code against it. I believe that the closest you will get is the [matlab report generator](http://www.mathworks.com/products/ML_reportgenerator/features.html#dynamic-reporting) which will provide some basic information from matlab scripts in a web dashboard format. [image]

I have had some better experience using [Plotly](https://plot.ly/matlab/) who have opensourced their matlab libraries.

[image: Plotly Example]

Comment: I want to create a UI like I can create in ShinyApp that would have buttons and text inputs. I don't see them in any of these. Also I need it to be a standalone web app. Seems not like it in the first case.